# Memory Leak ReactJs Application

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm new for this framework, I know this is duplicate Question, however i wanted to find the issue how to solved my problem.

Because every page of my project has a memory leak warning. I just watching videos in youtube about CRUD.

[image: Sample Image]

I have here my sample codes.

**My constructor:**

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        job_details:[]
    }
}
```

**My ComponentWillMount :**

```
componentWillMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    axios.get('/api/job_details/'+ id).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            job_details: response.data
        })
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

**My JSX:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="header">
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Careers</h1>
                    <center><p id="sub-header">Grabe the Opportunity Now!</p></center>
                </div>
                {this.state.job_details.map((details,i) => {
                    if(details.location == null)
                    {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <div className="container">
                                    <b>
                                    <h2 className="title">{details.position_name}</h2>
                                    </b>
                                    <p>{details.position_desc}</p>
                                    <Link to={"/job/online-application/"+ details.id} className="btn btn-outline-primary float-right">Apply</Link>
                                    <br/><br/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <br/><br/>
                                <div className="container">
                                    <b>
                                    <h2 className="title">{details.position_name} - {details.location} </h2>
                                    </b>
                                    <br/>
                                    <h5><b>Position Description</b></h5>
                                    <p>{details.position_desc}</p>

                                    <br/>
                                    <h5><b>Position Requirements </b></h5>
                                    <p>{details.position_requirements}</p>
                                    <Link to={"/job/online-application/"+ details.id } className="btn btn-outline-primary float-right">Apply</Link>
                                    <br/><br/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                })}
            </div>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Always add `props` to the `constructor` and then pass it to `super`.

Comment: Well the trouble could be outside the code you are showing. Is somebody else unmounting the component you are showing while you are waiting for the data to come through?

Answer (score 3):

change `ComponentWillMount` to `ComponentDidMount`..... literally you are calling `setState` in the lifecycle hook that occurs before the component mounts... then you get an error saying that you are calling set state on an unmounted component. If you put this logic in `componentDidMount` then the component will be mounted :)

Comment: hi Joey, can i have the sample?

Comment: `
componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    axios.get('/api/job_details/'+ id).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            job_details: response.data
        })
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Add the variable _isMounted in the jsx file:

```
  _isMounted = false;
```

Then add the code of `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true; //set _isMounted to true.

    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    axios.get('/api/job_details/'+ id).then(response => {
        if(_isMounted){
        this.setState({
            job_details: response.data
        })
        }
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Then add the   `componentWillUnmount()` method.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
}
```